# buffer-read-only when using button

Tags: buttons, read-only

I cannot understand why the following gives an error.  What can I do to solve the problem when I press on the button.

```
(buffer-read-only #<buffer *Help*>)
 insert("> Graphic Organisation \n\n")
```

In this code, I use `with-current-buffer` to temporarily switch to the `*Help*` buffer, make it writable, insert the text and button, and then set it back to read-only.  This should solve the problem with the read-only buffer.  But it does not work out that way.

```
(defun maces ()
  "Prints information about frames."
  (interactive)

  (with-help-window (help-buffer)

    (setq buffer-read-only nil)

    (insert-button "[1]" 'action
      (lambda (button)
        (insert "> Graphic Organisation \n\n")))
    (insert " Show graphic organisation")

    (setq buffer-read-only t)) )
```

Comment: FYI: You can just use `"*Help*"` instead of `(help-buffer)`, or vice versa. And you can use either of those instead of `(get-buffer "*Help*")`. IOW, both `with-help-window` and `with-current-buffer` accept a buffer name as arg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `(lambda (button) (insert "> Graphic Organisation \n\n"))` is invoked when the button is pushed.  And that happens in buffer `*Help*`, which is read-only.

Try adding a `(let ((read-only  nil))...)` wrapper around that `(insert...)` sexp.

Or if you expect to insert into some other buffer, which is not read-only, then use `with-current-buffer` inside the lambda form.

Comment: Have included `(setq buffer-read-only nil)` but still get the error.

Comment: I think I understand the answer now.  Have removed the current location of  `(setq buffer-read-only nil)` and `(setq buffer-read-only nil)` and introduced them inside the lambda function.  Would I need to also keep the lines as they are as well when writing the button and the information string `" Show Graphic Organisation"` ?

Comment: You say that the help buffer is read only but I manage to write to it, first time round (for button and description).  Why is this so?

Comment: Most of the code I have seen over the years used a let binding of the variable inhibit-read-only to a non-nil value.

Comment: @lawlist: Yes, that's OK too. It's not quite the same thing, as the doc string tells you.

Comment: @Dilna: You can write to a help buffer if you turn off its read-only state, or if you write to it before it's set to read-only.

Comment: @Dilna: Any time you want to write (insert) into a read-only buffer you need to make it writable. Doesn't matter when that time is. If it's read-only you need to make it writable to write into it.

Comment: Does that mean that I need to have  `(setq buffer-read-only nil)` before `insert-button` as well ?

Comment: Try, and see what happens. If you can insert then the buffer isn't read-only.

Comment: If I include the `(setq buffer-read-only nil)` inside the function, I get no errors.  even do I do not have an additional `(setq buffer-read-only nil)` just after `(setq buffer-read-only nil)`.  I thus wonder how the help buffer is not read only for the calls to `insert-button` and `insert`.  Can you explain what is happnening ?

Comment: Sorry; I don't understand what you're saying or not understanding. "an additional `(setq buffer-read-only nil)` just after `(setq buffer-read-only nil)`? I suggest you post a separate question for whatever question you have. Someone will no doubt try to answer it.

Comment: The source code for `with-help-window` shows that it arranges for `inhibit-read-only` to be set to `t` around the call to its body.  Important detail that is not mentioned in the docstring of `with-help-window`.